# PL/SQL Writing Unicode File

Tags: oracle, unicode, plsql, utl-file

I'm using Oracle 11g on Windows 7 with national character set equal to AL16UTF16.

I'm trying to write 3 cyrillic letters with the following PL/SQL code:

```
declare
  s nvarchar2(3):=nchr(1040) || nchr(1041) || nchr(1042);
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR('TEMP', 'test.txt', 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_NCHAR(fileHandler,s);
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
end;
```

The resulting file is 5 bytes long. If I open the file in Notepad++ I can see the following:
DLE DC1 DC2 with new line at the end (character 13+character 10). What is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of magic with line terminations in UTL_FILE in text mode.
You may experiance a different behaviour if you will be using some other OS.

to avoid it, you may use binary mode with conversion

```
fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TEMP', 'test.txt', 'wb');
UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (fileHandler, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s));
```

Comment: The change did not solve the problem. With the first version of the program the bytes written are:
16 17 18 13 10
The second version generates the following bytes:
0 16 0 17 0 18
But, what the desired result if Unicode should be:
254 255 4 16 4 17 4 18

Comment: That's true. I gave solution only for the line terminator. For correct encoding you may play with CONVERT and HEXTORAW functions.